# Div alignment different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a gradient background that surrounds the navigation menu of my site. For some reason this is aligned different in Chrome and Firefox.

I used WordPress to build the site.

Here are two snippets showing the difference:

[Chrome_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5sNF.png)

[Firefox_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGIek.png)

Here's the CSS used:

```
.nav-gradient {
     width: 650px;
     padding-top: 7%;
     margin-top: -7%;
     float: right;
     margin-right: -90px;
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your div

```
margin: 0 auto; /*this will centralize the div, horizontal. so that it is nice looking in the middle on different computer screens. */
```

Comment: Hi Ssmahi, I've tried your suggestion but did not have the desired outcome. Although adding `margin: 0 auto;` might centralise the div, it does not position it right at the top of the page (see screenshot taken in Firefox). If I decrease the `margin-top` value say to -12% instead of -7% (as set currently), the div might look OK in Chrome and be aligned at the very top of the page, but in Firefox it would go too far out of the page... I hope that makes sense. Any other suggestions please?